# What kind of destructuring does cl-loop support?

Tags: cl-lib, iteration

### 1. Summary

Is it possible to destructure an unordered plist in `cl-loop`'s `for`-clauses?

---

### 2. Details

From [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/For-Clauses.html) I would have expected destructuring to be universal, e.g. I would have expected

```
for (a . b) = data
```

and

```
for (a &rest b) = data
```

to do the same thing, and

```
for (&key a b) = '(:a 1 :b 2 :c 3)
```

to effectively allow destructuring plists. This doesn't seem to be the case.

---

### 3. Example

Consider the snippet

```
(cl-loop for plist in '((:a 1 :b 2 :c 3) nil) 
         for (&key a b) = plist
         collect (vector a b))
```

I would have expected the result to be

```
([1 2] [nil nil])
```

and instead I get

```
([1 :b] [nil nil])
```

i.e. `&key` is treated as a variable name, not as an argument list keyword.

Comment: I don't know why you'd expect that: the documentation says "similar in concept to argument lists", not "identical to"

Comment: @rpluim Mostly for consistency. Why have different notions and implementations for the same thing in one package? It just would make sense to have consistent destructuring everywhere.

Comment: That part of doc (especially the link) is misleading, however, after that part, only the support of the plain list (including dotted list and nested list) is documented, it doesn't mention it supports destructuring the Common Lisp argument, unlike for example cl-destructuring-bind's doc.

Comment: Bottom line: It isn't possible to get keyword destructuring. (Though in hindsight it anyway isn't really suitable for destructuring plists, as they have different behavior when it comes to unexpected symbols, and plists allow arbitrary symbols as keys, not just keyword symbols).